# Блок "Поделиться" от Яндекс не отображается

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Блок установлен при помощи кода:

```
<script src="https://yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.min.js" data-skip-moving></script>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.min.js" data-skip-moving></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,twitter,linkedin,viber,whatsapp,skype,telegram"></div>
```

На локальном сервере отображается. На сайте в Веб -- не отображается.
При этом в консоли пишет:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () share.min.js:1
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL>.
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в неправильных ссылках.

Система сборки, которую мы используем, добавила лишние суффиксы .min к адресам скриптов.